# Angular loading animation

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I just wondering if anyone could help me. I am writing angular app and I stack. I'm using php and MySQL on the server side and all works great. All the http requests are in the services. Sometimes when large amount of data is requested or response is taking a while for what ever reason there is a delay on the front end. I already have loading animation designed in css with use of svg. I have no clue how to implement it it my app. Desirable effect would be to display loader when data is incoming from the server.

I am not asking for ready solution but for some advice on what is the best practice to implement it within my app.

Below is example of my login service.

```js
'use strict';

app.factory('loginService', function($http, $location, sessionService) {
 // Service must return
 return {
  login: function(user, scope) {
   // Send credential to the server
   var $promise = $http.post('http://localhost:8888/myApi/api/login/user.php', user);
   $promise.then(function(msg) {
    var uid = msg.data;
    if(uid) {
     if(uid.status == 'success') {
      //scope.msgtxt = uid.response.success;
      sessionService.set('uid', uid.session);
      $location.path('/home');      
     } else {
      scope.msgtxt = uid.error;
     }
    } else {
     $location.path('/login');
    }
   })
  },
  logout: function() {
   sessionService.destroy('uid');
   $location.path('/login');
  },
  islogged: function() {
   var $checkSessionServer = $http.post('http://localhost:8888/myApi/api/login/check_session.php');
   return $checkSessionServer;
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/) automatically displays loading bars based on your `$http` requests, so you don't have to do anything to implement it.

> The idea is simple: Add a loading bar / progress bar whenever an XHR
>   request goes out in angular. Multiple requests within the same time
>   period get bundled together such that each response increments the
>   progress bar by the appropriate amount.

You can also change the HTML of the progress bar and spinner, so which allows you to make a really nice progress bar with minimal work.

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am, I just test it out works like a charm, this is fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +Wolfy Very glad to hear that I helped.